# How to keep Web Essential regions from breaking jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor-2, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 and Razor Web Pages (not MVC).

I have a jquery ajax that looks like this:

```
$("#test1").ready(function () {

    var test = { "loadTestList": "loadTestList" };

    function loadTestList(response) {
        var ddlTest = $('#test1');
        ddlTest.empty();

        ddlTest.append(
                $("<option></option>").text('All').val('All')
            );
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
            ddlTest.append(
                $("<option></option>").text(response[i].TestName).val(response[i].TestName)
            );
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "../Controllers/TestController.cshtml",
        data: test,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            loadTestList(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Sorry, there seems to be a problem contacting the Test server.");
            console.log(response.responseStatus);
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

This actually works.

Now I have my controller has code like this:

```
@* Controllers/TestController.cshtml *@
@{    
    if (IsPost && Request["loadTestList"] != null)
    {
        var tests = new TestRepository(new TestContext());
        var testslist = tests.Load();

        Json.Write(testslist, Response.Output);
    }
}@
```

And yes, this works too.

But when I do this:

```
@{    
    <!-- #region TestMe -->
    if (IsPost && Request["loadTestList"] != null)
    {
        var tests = new TestRepository(new TestContext());
        var testslist = tests.Load();

        Json.Write(testslist, Response.Output);
    }
    <!-- #endregion -->
}@
```

This breaks jQuery every time. $.ajax goes to error everytime.

So does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening? I really like regions, but I can't have it breaking the rest of jQuery.

Also why would this break jQuery in the first place if all I'm passing (through Json.Write) is testslist?

**NOTE:** TestController.cshtml has only server side code. No HTML at all.

Answer (score 0):

Inside @{  } block you can use standard c# precompiler directive:

```
#region [region_name]
#endregion
```

Inside

```
<script></script>
```

block use web essentials pattern for javaScript:

```
//#region [region_name]
//#endregion
```